# Integrate AdminLTE with MVC 5 Application

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-4, adminlte

I have a very basic MVC 5 Application which I am attempting to add AdminLTE to. I downloaded the AdminLTE Nuget package and added the code from the startup.html page to my MVC application's _Layout.cshtml page. I updated all the CSS and JS links to point to the right directory for my application.

Here is the code in the _Layout.cshtml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<!-- Theme style -->
<link href="~/admin-lte/css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/admin-lte/css/skins/skin-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
            <!-- Left navbar links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                    <a href="index3.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- SEARCH FORM -->
            <form class="form-inline ml-3">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Right navbar links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <!-- Messages Dropdown Menu -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="far fa-comments"></i>
                        <span class="badge badge-danger navbar-badge">3</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                            <!-- Message Start -->
                            <div class="media">
                                <img src="dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 mr-3 img-circle">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                                        Brad Diesel
                                        <span class="float-right text-sm text-danger"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <p class="text-sm">Call me whenever you can...</p>
                                    <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Message End -->
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                            <!-- Message Start -->
                            <div class="media">
                                <img src="dist/img/user8-128x128.jpg" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 img-circle mr-3">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                                        John Pierce
                                        <span class="float-right text-sm text-muted"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <p class="text-sm">I got your message bro</p>
                                    <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Message End -->
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                            <!-- Message Start -->
                            <div class="media">
                                <img src="dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 img-circle mr-3">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                                        Nora Silvester
                                        <span class="float-right text-sm text-warning"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <p class="text-sm">The subject goes here</p>
                                    <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Message End -->
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Messages</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!-- Notifications Dropdown Menu -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
                        <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge">15</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
                        <span class="dropdown-header">15 Notifications</span>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i> 4 new messages
                            <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">3 mins</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                            <i class="fas fa-users mr-2"></i> 8 friend requests
                            <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">12 hours</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                            <i class="fas fa-file mr-2"></i> 3 new reports
                            <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">2 days</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Notifications</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-widget="control-sidebar" data-slide="true" href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.navbar -->
        <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
        <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
            <!-- Brand Logo -->
            <a href="index3.html" class="brand-link">
                <img src="dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
                     style="opacity: .8">
                <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">AdminLTE 3</span>
            </a>
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="sidebar">
                <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
                <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <a href="#" class="d-block">Alexander Pierce</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
                <nav class="mt-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                        <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
                             with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
                        <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Starter Pages
                                    <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                                </p>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
                                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                        <p>Active Page</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                        <p>Inactive Page</p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Simple Link
                                    <span class="right badge badge-danger">New</span>
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar -->
        </aside>
        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Starter Page</h1>
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Starter Page</li>
                            </ol>
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div><!-- /.row -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.content-header -->
            <!-- Main content -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
                                        content.
                                    </p>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
                                        content.
                                    </p>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.card -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h5 class="m-0">Featured</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h6 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h6>
                                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h5 class="m-0">Featured</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h6 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h6>
                                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
        <!-- Control Sidebar -->
        <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
            <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
            <div class="p-3">
                <h5>Title</h5>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
            </div>
        </aside>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
        <!-- Main Footer -->
        <footer class="main-footer">
            <!-- To the right -->
            <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-inline">
                Anything you want
            </div>
            <!-- Default to the left -->
            <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2019 <a href="https://adminlte.io">AdminLTE.io</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
        </footer>
    </div>
}
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is what the Home page currently looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chXVh.png) It seems like not all the JS and/or CSS is being loaded but I have no idea what is missing as the Chrome console is not showing any errors. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please check your image paths, may be you need to use ResolvePath or add / or ~/ to these “dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png” https://html.developreference.com/article/15753951/Asp.net+MVC+different+routes+cause+relative+addressing+issues

Comment: I got that ironed out. It was just a few images that were missing so I wasn't super concerned about that. The page still doesn't render properly. It's like it's not loading some of the CSS or something. All the links look correct however.

Comment: In the path source inside Chrome click on each included file link to make sure it resolves. Also something could be overriding something so try moving these around or commenting some of them out.

Comment: Everything appears to be resolving correctly. :(

Comment: Admin lte is one of the similar ones to integrate in .net it will be a path issue if anything